# How do I get a paginated view to display rel="next/previous" tags?

Tags: views, uri

Using Drupal 7.

I've got several views (most of which listing articles which have been posted) that paginate and I'd like to add;

```
<link rel="prev" href="http://example.com/recent-articles?page=0" />
<link rel="next" href="http://example.com/recent-articles?page=2" />
```

links to them.

How do I do this? A module is preferred, changing the `php` files would preferably be avoided.

Things I've tried:

- [Lightbox2](https://www.drupal.org/project/lightbox2) (module)
- [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/Metatag) (module)
- [Meta tags quick](https://www.drupal.org/project/Metatags_quick) (module)
- [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) controls themselves
- [REL Links](https://www.drupal.org/project/rel_links) (module)

Comment: have you checked pager options in views

Comment: Yes, as stated in the question - I've tried the views controls themselves. This includes the controls available in the specific view.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to override [`theme_pager_previous()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21pager.inc/function/theme_pager_previous/7) and [`theme_pager_next()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21pager.inc/function/theme_pager_previous/7) (easiest to do in your theme):

```
function MYTHEME_pager_previous($vars) {
  $text = $variables['text'];
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $interval = $variables['interval'];
  $parameters = $variables['parameters'];
  global $pager_page_array;
  $output = '';

  // If we are anywhere but the first page
  if ($pager_page_array[$element] > 0) {
    $page_new = pager_load_array($pager_page_array[$element] - $interval, $element, $pager_page_array);

    // Changes from core function start here.
    $attributes = array('rel' => 'prev');

    // If the previous page is the first page, mark the link as such.
    if ($page_new[$element] == 0) {
      $output = theme('pager_first', array('text' => $text, 'element' => $element, 'parameters' => $parameters, 'attributes' => $attributes));
    }
    // The previous page is not the first page.
    else {
      $output = theme('pager_link', array('text' => $text, 'page_new' => $page_new, 'element' => $element, 'parameters' => $parameters, 'attributes' => $attributes));
    }
  }

  return $output;
}
```

And the same thing for pager_next.

Comment: This is an incorrect answer as the `rel="next/prev"` must be placed in the `<head>` not in the pager link.
See https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663744

Comment: Would [`drupal_add_html_head`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_html_head/7) work here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is a contrib module outside of D.O. that does the trick.

https://github.com/nlisgo/nextprev_links

Have you already tried this one?

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue of combining multiple views and give the pager so they all combined, and can accessible by the pager. I have asked previously on DA and here is the link just see the detail of answer and question you will automatically will get idea how you can do it.

[How to add pager at the bottom which allow shifting between views?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/191633/how-to-add-pager-at-the-bottom-which-allow-shifting-between-views)

Basically, you can do by this views, all your articles in one views and add new display page and go increasing offset +1 in pager for subsequent pages. Just follow the answer you will get idea. And lastly add the pager as described in the answer to combine all.