# RSS view with pager

Tags: 7, views

I have view with RSS feed enabled, but i cant figure out how to make RSS with pager like original page in view.
View is simple, has title, body, but there are 500 entries so pager is a must.

I have tried Services views module, but the results are same. In code preview there is no pager showing up.

Comment: If you are looking for a full-blown pager, like what views can produce in an HTML output, I'm not sure that's possible. RSS is just XML-encoded data, not an actual page that can be formatted. Are you instead looking for ways to implement `<link rel="next"` or `<link rel="previous"` tags as additional metadata, like what's discussed in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301392/pagination-in-feeds-like-atom-and-rss)?

Comment: I am not coder so not sure, but it looks like a solution. Any idea how to implement that in RSS view or Service view ?

Comment: Beyond some custom code that injects the needed `<link>` tags into the header (maybe with drupal_add_html_head()) I'm not personally sure. It looks like a related answer appears in [this post](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/125993/how-to-get-paginated-views-to-display-rel-next-previous-tags), but it might not be directly applicable. Maybe someone else will be able to point-out a module-driven way.